# "Edit with IDLE" option missing Python 3.6

Tags: python

I am using Python 3.6 and the "Edit with IDLE" option is missing. I have read numerous threads here on Stack Overflow and other websites about editing the registry, but nothing works. I have re-installed completely Python 3.6, also tried with Python 2.7 but I just don't get the option anymore. Any ideas?

Comment: Do you mean when you right click on a file you don't have the option? Also, what operating system?

Comment: Have you tried re-installing or even just restarting the PC?

Comment: Yes when I right click I don't have the option / Yes I tried re-installing as I said, also restarting PC / Yes IDLE works fine

Comment: Not a direct answer to the question, but I will just say that IDLE is not a particularly well-featured editor. You may want to consider installing a dedicated programmer's text editor and configuring it for your Python installation(s). There are many such programs with a wide variety of features and capabilities, and (IMO) IDLE does not compete particularly well with pretty much any of them.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not strictly a programming question, but here are the registry keys that are responsible for the context menu entries on Python files in the Windows Explorer.

I've made an "Edit with IDLE" sub-menu as there are multiple versions of Python installed on my machine.

*(**Disclaimer:** This is hand-crafted and will not be removed automatically when you uninstall Python. You have to clean it up yourself.)*

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Python.File\shell\editwithidle]
"MUIVerb"="&Edit with IDLE"
"Subcommands"=""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Python.File\shell\editwithidle\shell]

; Python 2.7 -----------------------------------------------------------------------

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Python.File\shell\editwithidle\shell\edit27-32]
"MUIVerb"="Edit with IDLE 2.7 (32-bit)"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Python.File\shell\editwithidle\shell\edit27-32\command]
@="\"C:\\Python27\\pythonw.exe\" \"C:\\Python27\\Lib\\idlelib\\idle.pyw\" -e \"%1\""

; Python 3.6 -----------------------------------------------------------------------

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Python.File\shell\editwithidle\shell\edit36-32]
"MUIVerb"="Edit with IDLE 3.6 (32-bit)"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Python.File\shell\editwithidle\shell\edit36-32\command]
@="\"C:\\Python36\\pythonw.exe\" -m idlelib \"%L\" %*"
```

Of course change the paths according to your installation directories. Add/remove sections according to the installed Python versions. Then save as .reg file and import.

Also note that I've picked sensible subkey names like `edit36-32`. It's not strictly required, these only need to be unique, but if I'm creating registry entries, I like them to contain what they say. So, adapt those accordingly.

---

If you have only one Python version installed and never plan on getting a second installation, or if you like the menu entries in the top level instead of in a sub-menu:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Python.File\shell\editwithidle]
@="Edit with IDLE 3.6 (32-bit)"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Python.File\shell\editwithidle\command]
@="\"C:\\Python36\\pythonw.exe\" -m idlelib \"%L\" %*"
```

Comment: I have Python 2.7 and 3.6 but 3.6 is installed somewhere in AppData by default. Should it be in C:\? I will try your solution later but I'm a bit pessimistic as I have already tried many modifications to the registry without success.

Comment: There is no reason to be pessimistic. This is the way to add menu entries to any file type. You can make up your own entries if you want, for tasks that you do often. As I said, I've hand-crafted the above one - there's no magic involved. When you don't select "install for all users" during the Python installation, then the installer will put it into your AppData folder - in exchange for not requiring admin rights during installation. I prefer my Python to be in a predictable place, so I picked "for all users" and a short path, too.

Comment: Ok I have tried the .reg file you mentioned above for 2 version of Python, but it doesn't show me any of the "Edit with IDLE" options when I right click a .py file. Actually, I reset the default apps to open .py files and now it doesn't have a default app. What should I set it to? Not sure if it has anything to do with this though.

Comment: Okay, check the following things using regedit: **1)** There should be a key `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.py` with a default value of `Python.File`. **2)** `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Python.File\shell`  should contain the sub-key structure from the .reg file, and all the right paths for your system. **3)** There should **NOT** be a `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\.py` entry. If there is, rename it, or delete it. (If things are all underneath `HKEY_CURRENT_USER` for you, then you either have to re-install Python for all users, or adapt all the key names in the .reg file. I'd prefer the "for all" install.)

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply. In the meantime I was looking at the registry and this is what the Python.File folder looks like now: https://imgur.com/a/G06g5gv There's an "Edit with IDLE" pointing to Python 2.7 and then a "editwithidle" that also contains Python 2.7 and 3.6... Is that how it is supposed to be? I will now check what you said in your post above.

Comment: Yeah, that's how it supposed to be when you have imported my .reg file above without making any changes to it, instead of adapting it to your installation. The upper in the screenshot is the one that the Python installer creates. The lower part comes from my reg file.

Comment: The 3 things you mentioned above finally solved the issue! You're my hero :-)

Comment: You're welcome. And you have learned how to create custom context menu entries in Explorer today!

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem before. Obviously reinstalling the system will work, but I am kidding, you don't have to do that. I will suggest one way which will work for sure as follows:
1. open regedit
2. under edit: search for "python"
3. delete any term you find and search for next until all terms related to "python" is deleted.
4. Reinstall python, any version you want, Done!!!