# Python "Edit with IDLE" missing/damaged register keys

Tags: python, python-idle, regedit

I recently installed Python 3.11.6 along side my previous python 3.9.7 installation. I did something similar on another machine and the result was that both versions' IDLE showed up in the context menu when for ".py" file. However on the current machine the whole "Edit with IDLE" context menu entry got nuked...

Currently, when right-clicking to any ".py" file the "Edit with IDLE" is not present.

I already checked the following threads:

- ["Edit with IDLE" option missing from context menu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29179631/edit-with-idle-option-missing-from-context-menu)
- ["Edit with IDLE" option missing Python 3.6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50953131/edit-with-idle-option-missing-python-3-6)

And, I do have the ".py" files associated with `...\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\python.exe` as required, while for the register file something clearly broke:

Initially under "Python.File" there were pairs of keys, one for 3.11.6 and one for 3.9.7, however after I ran the installer for both versions in "repair mode" now only the top key "Python.File" remains, and no subkeys. I did run again the repair for both installations, as well as uninstalling and reinstalling python 3.11.6, but to no avail...

Given that such keys are what make "Edit with IDLE" a thing, restoring them seems to me the only option to solve the issue. Thus, are there automated procedures to rebuild the correct keys in the registry? Or alternatively, what is the expected structure of keys required to make the "Edit with IDLE" work for both versions?

If anyone could provide me a template, it will be of great help!

Note: I do not have any other python installation present on the machine (such as the Windows store one), just the two versions stated above, installed with the official Windows installer.